# How to use the DIA SDK to read *code* (specifically including jump tables)?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, debug-symbols, pdb-files, dia-sdk

I'm using the [DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) from C#.

Right now I have something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var v = new DiaSource();
    v.loadDataForExe("Temp.exe", null, null);  // native, with symbols

    Dia2Lib.IDiaSession session;
    v.openSession(out session);
        var items = new Stack<KeyValuePair<IDiaSymbol, int>>();

    items.Push(new KeyValuePair<IDiaSymbol, int>(session.globalScope, 0));
    while (items.Count > 0)
    {
        var pair = items.Pop();

        var symbol = pair.Key;
        if (symbol.function != 0)
        {
            // What do I do?
        }

        // Push child symbols onto stack
        IDiaEnumSymbols enumSymbols;
        symbol.findChildren(SymTagEnum.SymTagNull, null, 0, out enumSymbols);
        if (enumSymbols != null)
        {
            foreach (IDiaSymbol child in enumSymbols)
            {
                if (symbol.symIndexId == child.symIndexId)
                {
                    // Why do some nodes contain themselves?
                    // Break out if that's the case...
                    break;
                }
                items.Push(
                    new KeyValuePair<IDiaSymbol, int>(child, pair.Value + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about using the DIA SDK to browse the code, and, specifically, find any jump tables and their target addresses (i.e. those produced by the `switch` statement) in my executable?

I have already verified that they exist, I just don't know how to access them.

<sub>I tagged C# because I'm using C# with COM, but I also tagged C++ because the SDK is originally in C++ (with COM). Feel free to remove either that might be inappropriate; thanks.</sub>